# Apache Validator or Hibernate Validator Alternative

Tags: java, validation

I'm trying to find a configurable/dynamic validator for normal Pojo class.

The application I'm developing is pretty simple..

XML -> Pojo Object -> Validation -> insert into database.

I'm trying to make the validation dynamic so I can change it on the fly as long I have written the validation before.

This is a stand-alone application.

1) Each class validation can be configure via XML

2) Custom validation can be written first, something like command object.

I'm doing literature research first. So I am wondering the following questions.

1) Will Apache Validator or Hibernate Validator meet my requirements?

2) Are there alternative that I should consider?

3) If they can't meet my requirement, does it mean I have customize it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To me, [`HibernateValidator`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate-validator/4.0.2.GA/hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA-dist.zip/download?use_mirror=nchc) is best, since it just requires annotaions without additional effort (developing logic for validation). and can also be customized as the need arises.

Comment: Additionally, the Spring MVC (If you're using it) has an in-build `Validator` (an Interface) support. You might think of it, it you were to need.

Comment: Is a stand alone application, not web application.

Comment: As far as I understand you want really dynamic validation, so you can't use HibernateValidator because it makes you to annotate your fields or properties..., Apache Validators is a combination of server side and client side validation, configured via XML.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh hmm will apache validator solve my problem? if not does that means I need to create my own API?

Comment: Another one validator framework which may be helpful: http://jodd.org/doc/vtor/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/)
It's a validation framework, still maintained, light and extensible.

You can write your constraints using annotations, pojos, or XML
Complex contraints can be written, for exemple dynamic and/or custom checks, based on multiple fields written in script languages (groovy, ruby, javascript, etc)

The [userguide](http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) is well done

I cannot tell if it's better than apache validator or hibernate validator, I didn't well tested them. But I use OVal for a while now, and I'm quite sure it fulfill your needs

Comment: Thanks cporte, I am going to request man hours for research soon. Have you use apache validator or hibernate validator? Care to do a comparison ? I only have max 1~3 day man days for this "POC". if possible please let us know what kind of project did you use it on.

Comment: As I said, I cannot really do a comparison as I only looked at them quickly to make a decision. Apache validator seemed to be XML only (we have many cases where annotations are easier). For Hibernate Validator, when we made the decision (late 2010) it seemed too heavy compared to OVal, and we had a few month ago some issues with another Hibernate component. But as I'm looking again at it, it can also do the job I think. Depends on you other componant in you stack.

Comment: For our project, we needed an independant componant as our stack is not conventionnal. We have a graph database without ORM for the persistence, a custom layer to create some DTO to send to an heavy client (we're in client/server), and a command pattern based layer for modifications coming from clients. This layer holds the validation and we sometimes have different commands on the same class that need different validations

Answer (score 0):

Another good alternative for hibernate-validator is [Apache BVal](https://bval.apache.org/)

Get the validator factory by the following code

```
ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation
                       .byProvider(ApacheValidationProvider.class)
                       .configure()
                       .buildValidatorFactory();
```